# Cordova Android Emulator giving Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, android-emulator, phonegap

I am getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` for `let` declaration, the code is working fine when tested with APK on real device. I am checking for the error by inspecting device from chrome://inspect/#devices.

**Javascript code is:**

```
let options = {
    width: 256,
    height: 256,
    colorDark: "#000000",
    colorLight: "#ffffff",
};
```

**Getting Error:**`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

Comment: `colorLight: "#ffffff",` - comma in the end?

Comment: @oss, Removed, still same error